# Use prop as key in svelte component, default props return undefined

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to have props on a svelte component be used as a key on an object defined in the component. While I can do this successfully if the props are explicitly set on the component, the default props return undefined.

**Button.svelte**

```
<script>
const variants = {
  primary: 'btn-primary',
  secondary: 'btn-secondary',
  plain: 'btn-plain',
}

export let variant = 'secondary';

<button class="btn {variants[variant]}"></button>
```

**App.svelte**

```
import Button from './Button.svelte';

<Button variant="primary" />  <-- renders <button class="btn btn-primary" />
<Button /> <-- renders <button class="btn undefined" />
```

How can I have this use the default prop as the key so I get `<button class="btn btn-secondary" />`?

Comment: In this REPL everything works as expected: https://svelte.dev/repl/4c5509f5da54410d90a18efc8ccb5159?version=3.24.1

Comment: this should work, can you verify if this is indeed the code you used in the actual project ? maybe there are some stray ' or " hanging around ?

Comment: Well I'll be. This does work like I originally had it.I was developing and seeing this in a storybook instance at first. So maybe that had something to do with it, or like you said I had a stray quote somewhere. Thanks for the fresh set of eyes.